# datenum and matrix column string conversion

Tags: matlab

I want to convert the second column of table T using datenum.

The elements of this column are '`09:30:31.848`', '`15:35:31.325`', etc. When I use `datenum('09:30:31.848','HH:MM:SS.FFF')` everything works, but when I want to apply datenum to the whole column it doesn't work. I tried this command `datenum(T(:,2),'HH:MM:SS.FFF')` and I receive this error message:

> "The input to DATENUM was not an array of character vectors"

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MhrL.png) a snapshot of T

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the data from the table, but rather a slice of the table (so its stays a table). Refer to the data in the table using `T.colName`:

```
times_string = ['09:30:31.848'; '15:35:31.325'];
T = table(times_string)
times_num = datenum(T.times_string, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF')
```

Alternatively, you can slice the table using curly braces to extract the data (if you want to use the column number instead of name):

```
times_num = datenum(T{:,2}, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF')
```